# Check for constraint on table

Tags: sql-server

If I check for a column's existance as follows, before adding it, how would I do the equivalent for a UNIQUE constraint?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('[Table]') AND [Name]='Column')
    ALTER TABLE [Table] 
    ADD 
    [Column] varchar(500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from sys.objects where type = 'uq' and parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('[Table]')

Answer (score 1):

Something like this for a constraint FK_myTable (SQL 2000):

```
if not exists ( select *
    from sysconstraints sc
    inner join sysobjects tbl on sc.id = tbl.id
    inner join sysobjects con on sc.constid = con.id
    where tbl.name = 'myTable' and con.name = 'FK_myTable' )
```

Comment: I believe that sysconstraints and sysobjects have been deprecated and you are no longer supposed to use them.

Comment: I'm still living in a cave and using SQL 2000 :)